# Geofencing radius distribution/ratio across multiple geofences

Tags: python, r, geometry, gis, geofencing

I understand that this problem might be simple geometry, but Im using specific shapefiles for a geographical area and looking for a specific gis solution (hopefully code).

[image]

Essentially Id like to find the area of black that covers each separate geographical bounds. What percentage covers the red area, blue area, and then green?

I have coordinates of the center, as well as shapefiles (.shp). The radius is known. No preference on library other than it being open source (R and Python).

Comment: What data do you have? Do you have coordinates of the center? Do you have the radius? Do you have the shapefiles? Which library do you use?

Comment: @EricDuminil  have coordinates of the center, as well as shapefiles (.shp). The radius is known. No preference on library other than it being open source. Ive updated the question.

Comment: Look at intersection

Answer (score 0):

Those geometries could be loaded to PostGIS database, if you may consider such option. After that you may do simple SQL query, using built-in functions `st_buffier()` and `st_intersection()` to get desired output. Otherwise, you may use Python implementation of GDAL library.